# How to show arabic text in textview

Tags: java, android, arabic, textview

I'd like to know the unique codes of each Arabic letter to display the arabic text as a textview.

When I am giving straight as a string but it wont display like arabic textual format. It shows every letter seperated. I tried few links from google. But i didnt get exactly whaty i am looking for.

Actually I am looking for unique code of every arabic letter. So that i can display my sentence in arabic textual format.

Comment: It shows every letter seperated ??

Comment: I guess you are testing on an emulator. I faced this problem and found out that emulators do not support arabic for old SDKs. Try using an emulator for SDK 3.0 or higher.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it works for you, otherwise post some response that the solution is not working.

Comment: i would like to ask one more question to you which is related to google maos ?shall i ?

Comment: @jigar and Mohamed_abdallah  i want to draw a line between two locations i got one link but initially it works fine but later when am running the same code it is giving some problem here is the link which contains http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895184/getting-issue-drawing-line-in-map-between-two-locations-in-android-sdkmy code and logcat details and layout as well plz help me out from this ?can any help me out from this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0600.pdf) is the uni-code for each Arabic letter. May be you need to use different fonts also.